# Unable to rebuild index oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a scenario wherein I seek to trigger a reorg in a scenario.
Following is the sample code for the same:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ALPHA.BETA
    AFTER STARTUP ON DATABASE
    DECLARE
        DAY NUMBER;
        HOUR NUMBER;
        RUN_DATE NUMBER := 3;
        RUN_HOUR NUMBER := 12;
    BEGIN
        SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') INTO DAY FROM DUAL;
        SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24') INTO HOUR FROM DUAL;
        IF( DAY = RUN_DATE AND HOUR < RUN_HOUR ) THEN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ALPHA."BETA" MOVE TABLESPACE ALPHA2 PARALLEL 15';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ALPHA."BETA~0" REBUILD ONLINE PARALLEL 8';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ALPHA."BETA" MOVE ONLINE LOB(GAAMA) STORE AS (TABLESPACE ALPHA2) PARALLEL 15;
        END IF;
    END BETA;
/
```

The above triggers throws ORA-12838 exception

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: Do you really like to move tablespace on every database startup?

Comment: Result of `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D')` depends on `NLS_TERRITORY` settings.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ora-12838 was thrown when using parallel

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Kind of. The IF is supposed to make sure that it moves only on a certain day and within a certain time

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thats new knowledge to me :) The sysdate works for me as of now so it should do :)